# DropDownListFor() helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I've been playing with this HTML Helper for awhile now, following all sorts of examples which in theory accomplish the same end result.  However, I can't seem to produce the end result.

Maybe someone can see what I'm doing wrong before I go back to iterating out select options with a foreach.  It would be nice to lock in how this helper works, less code than a select with a foreach().

Edit controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        if (id != "")
        {

            UserViewModel user = (from u in db.Users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(id))
                                  from ur in u.Roles
                                  join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id

                                  select new UserViewModel
                                  {
                                      UserId = u.Id,
                                      DisplayName = u.DisplayName,
                                      Role = r.Name,
                                      RoleId = r.Id

                                  }
                       ).FirstOrDefault();

            //Select List items for select list
            var roles = db.Roles.Select(r => new SelectListItem { Value = r.Id, Text = r.Name });

            //select list with selected value
            user.Roles = new SelectList(roles,"Value", "Text", user.RoleId);

            
            return View(user);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

View;

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Role, Model.Roles, null, new { @class = "form-control" })

      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the question ? and what's the expected result , you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
var roles = db.Roles.Select(r => new SelectListItem { Value = r.Id, Text = r.Name });
```

creates `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

```
user.Roles = new SelectList(roles,"Value", "Text", user.RoleId);
```

just creates another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from it so its just pointless extra overhead and since your binding to a property in your model, the last paramater (`user.RoleId`) is ignored and also pointless

It should be just

```
user.Roles = db.Roles.Select(r => new SelectListItem { Value = r.Id, Text = r.Name });
```

When your create this `SelectList` you setting the value to the `Id` property of `Role` but you then attempting to bind to the `Role` property of `UserViewModel` instead of the `RoleId` property. Because the value of `Role` will not match one of the option values the first option in the dropdownlist will always be selected (because something has to be).

Change the code in your view to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleId, Model.Roles, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If the value of `RoleId` matches one of the option values, then it will be selected.

Side note: your `Role` property in your view model seems unnecessary, as does the need to create a join to the `Roles` table in your query.

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I was over doing it, appreciate the thorough explanation!  Works like a charm now.